# Wrap list parent in div with wp_nav_menu menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

Hello I have a menu with parent and children. Here is the code I am using to display it:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Menu')); ?>
```

This spits out something like this:

```
<div class="main-menu-menu-container">
    <ul class="main-menu-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="">Parent</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a>Child</a></li>
                <li><a>Child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="">Parent</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a>Child</a></li>
                <li><a>Child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="">Parent</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a>Child</a></li>
                <li><a>Child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any way to use arguments such as items_wrap to remove the overall `<ul>` and turn the parent list items into divs? So the html would look like this:

```
<div class="main-menu-menu-container">
    <div>
        <a href="">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a>Child</a></li>
            <li><a>Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a>Child</a></li>
            <li><a>Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a>Child</a></li>
            <li><a>Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its a pretty insane request so if its not possible its fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WordPress make use of `Walkers` you can extend the class `Walker_Nav_Menu` with your own and pass the instance of it to the function `wp_nav_menu`.

So your call will be:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'   => 'Main Menu'
    'walker' => new Custom_Nav_Walker()
) ); ?>
```

Then in a separated file create the class `Custom_Nav_Walker` that will be your walker.

The class extends two methods of `Walker_Nav_Menu` that are `start_el` and `end_el`. The code within them is pretty the same of the main class, except that we introduce a little tweak to wrap the nav items with a `div`.

WordPress unfortunately mix up php and html code sometimes using string like this one `$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';`

Within the `Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el` you'll find that line of code that is the opened tag for all of the list items ( the method is called everytime a new item need to be added to the list ).

If we change it with this one `$output .= $indent . (0 === $depth ? '<div ' : '<li ' ) . $id . $class_names . '>';` we'll use the `div` tag for all of the items at the first level.

Then in the method `end_el` we change this one `$output .= "</li>{$n}";` with `$output .= (0 === $depth ? "</div>{$n}" : "</li>{$n}");` so we can close the previously opened `div` tag.

Unfortunately unless you deep into complicated regexp this is the best and rapid solution to achive your goal.

The problem with this solution is that you must extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class and override the two methods above, meaning unnecessary code to maintain in case of WordPress change something.

Here the entire subclass used as walker for the menu.

```
class Custom_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [], $id = 0 ) {

    if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
        $t = '';
        $n = '';
    } else {
        $t = "\t";
        $n = "\n";
    }
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

    $classes   = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    /**
     * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     *
     * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

    /**
     * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
     *
     * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
     * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
     * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    /**
     * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
     *
     * @since 3.0.1
     * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
     *
     * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
     * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
     * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . (0 === $depth ? '<div ' : '<li ' ) . $id . $class_names . '>';

    $atts           = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? $item->xfn : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';

    /**
     * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
     *
     * @since 3.6.0
     * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
     *
     * @param array $atts {
     *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
     *
     *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
     *     @type string $target Target attribute.
     *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
     *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
     * }
     * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
     * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value       = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

    /**
     * Filters a menu item's title.
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     *
     * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
     * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
     * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

    $item_output  = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    /**
     * Filters a menu item's starting output.
     *
     * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
     * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
     * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
     * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}

public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [] ) {

    if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
        $t = '';
        $n = '';
    } else {
        $t = "\t";
        $n = "\n";
    }
    $output .= (0 === $depth ? "</div>{$n}" : "</li>{$n}");
}
```

}

I leave it the comments blocks from the original methods, but you get rid of them if you don't want to have info about the filters.

The class `Walker_Nav_Menu` is located into `wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with jQuery if anyone is interested.

```
jQuery('.main-menu-menu-container ul').wrap('<div class="parent"/>').contents().unwrap();
jQuery('.main-menu-menu-container .menu-item-has-children').wrap('<div class="child"/>').contents().unwrap();
```

I am still interested to know if its possible using php, so if anyone has a solution let me know!